# How I can add security patch for magento 2.2.6 without updating magento

Tags: magento2, security, patches, sql

> I have Magento 2.2.6
>
> I want to update security patch
>
> I have lost my server databases (maybe SQL injection)
>
> my questions

1)How to update security patches?

2)Is it will helpful?

3)Is there any other ways to protect my Magento 2 store?

Answer (score 0):

Please download the security patch from magento website `https://magento.com/security` according to your magento version. Upload it on your server root and apply it using below command:

```
patch -p1 < [PATCH FILE NAME].patch
```

Comment: i went to this link but no download option https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.2.6-and-2.1.15-security-update

Comment: I understand, I usually works in Magento EE, so I usually send an email to magento and they provide us everything. Please try writing an email to "support@magento.com"

Comment: i wite email to that email .....